# Can send messages to Azure EventHub but RegisterEventProcessorAsync doesn't receive anything

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-worker-roles, servicebus

I have followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-framework-getstarted-receive-eph to create a new EventProcessor using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IEventProcessor. The main difference being I'm running an Azure CloudService / WorkerRole as opposed to a console application. I can run the worker role fine locally.

I've copied in the boiler plate code including:

```
Task IEventProcessor.OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)...
```

and

```
async Task IEventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
```

And in the worker role `Run()` method I've put in `_eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<EventProcessor>(_eventProcessorOptions).Wait();`

When I debug the worker role locally the `IEventProcessor.OpenAsync` method is called, but the `ProcessEventsAsync` never gets called. I have checked that I'm using the correct eventhub, consumer, and that the blob storage connection is correct. I can send messages to the eventhub but I'm at a loss as to why the processor isn't picking them up. It would error for instance if the connection settings to the event hub were incorrect. But no errors are being logged at all.

Any ideas why it won't receive messages from the EventHub?

Comment: Have you tried to create a console application, then remote to your worker role VM and run the console application for narrow this issue?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are sending messages at all? Did you set up some kind of device simulator that generates messages?